# Restricting users that do not follow an account from viewing certain fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Currently I have an accounts endpoint /api/accounts/ and also more specific endpoints such as /api/accounts/1/followers

The users who follow the account to be able to see all their fields (username, profile picture, posts, followers, ...) but users who do not should only see their username and profile picture.

I have tried setting the queryset in the accounts viewset to only accounts the user folllows, but this raises a problem as it would prevent the user from discovering more accounts. I want it to be similar to instagram where discovering accounts is still possible but you cannot view their posts and etc. until you follow them or they are public.

Comment: you using rest_framework ?

Comment: @rgermain yes, I am